# qrcode generator in google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, qr-code

I am wondering what the options are for generating QRCode with google appengine python
At the moment I use the google chart API which is being deprecated
There is a Cython example I know of as well as in C (java etc)- A pure Python implementation would work I imagine 
Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PyQRNativeGAE](https://github.com/bernii/PyQRNativeGAE) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Did not work as it requires PIL which is unavailable.

Comment: @Jonny no it does not, PyQRNativeGAE.py is the version you must use.

Comment: I did try importing only that, contrary to the instruction on the github page, but the PyQRNativeGAE.py includes PyQRNative.py which in turn includes PIL on line 2 - and it errors out just there.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you asked, but generating QRCodes on the client side using http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-qrcode/ works for me (in pages served up from App Engine, though that's coincidental in this case, since the hard part is done in the browser).

Comment: Thanks nice to know about that option

Comment: This one worked good. But would be nice to have something smaller than 256x256 pixels which is just too huge.